# Explanation/How to use the Lattice isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I am having trouble understanding some of the wordings of the Lattice isomorphism theorem (Also known as 4th isomorphism theorem) in group theory. I quote here the theorem as in *Dummit and Foote*

> Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Then there is a bijection from the set of subgroups of $A$ of $G$ which contain $N$ onto the set of subgroups $ \overline{A}=A/N$ of $G/N$. In particular every subgroup of $\overline{G}$ is of the form $A/N$ for some subgroup $A$ of $G$ containing $N$.

I'm a bit lost on the part where it says "Then there is  bijection from the set of ......"

1. What exactly do they mean there is a bijection?. Do they mean this in the sense there is literally a bijection or are they using this word loosely?
2. How can one use this particular property to prove something useful? :)
   My Professor used to say that this is the most natural of the isomorphism theorems but I just don't see/get it.

Can someone be kind enough to explain this better?. If you can include a typical example where this theorem is used can clear things up a bit.

Thanks

**Edit**

> Question: Let $N$ be a order $7$ normal subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $G/N \cong D_{10}$ the dihedral group of order $10$. I want to prove that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $35$.

Here is how I proceed. Since the given dihedral group has a normal subgroup (The cyclic subgroup of order $5$), $G/N$ must also have such a subgroup $M$. Now by the lattice isomorphism theorem, $M=A/N$ for some subgroup $A$ of $G$ containing $N$. Can I immediately conclude that $A$ is normal in $G$ here without referring to the index of $A$ in $G$?. (It turns out that $A$ in this instance has index $2$ so normal in $G$).

Comment: Yup the wordings in Dummit's are challenging :D))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set of *all* subgroups $A$ of $G$ such that $N\subseteq A$. Let $T$ be the set of all subgroups of $G/N$. The claim is that there is a bijection between the sets $S$ and $T$. The use of the word bijection is the usual one: there exists a function $\psi:S\to T$ which is both injective and surjective.

Side remark: The theorem is much stronger. Each of the sets $S$ and $T$ above are in fact lattices and the bijection is a lattice isomorphism. Moreover, the isomorphism preserves and reflects normality.

Applications:

1) A normal subgroup $N\subseteq G$ is maximal (i.e., no subgroup $H$ exists with $N\subseteq H \subseteq G$) iff the index of $N$ in $G$ is a prime number.

2) Let $N$ be normal in $G$. Then $G/N$ is simple iff there exists no normal subgroups $K$ of $G$ with $N\subset K \subset G$.

A similar result holds for rings, giving the classical and very important application

3) If $I$ is an ideal in a commutative ring $R$, then $R/I$ is a field iff $I$ is maximal in $R$. This gives a very efficient way to building fields.

Answer to you later edit: Yes, normality is both preserved and reflected by the bijection. That means that if $\psi(A)=H$, then $A$ is normal in $G$ iff $H$ is normal in $G/N$. Most other properties of groups though will not be preserved or reflected in this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have question though. Because of this bijective property can I conclude something like: If a subgroup of $G$ has a certain property then there is a subgroup $A/N$ of $G/N$ that has the same property with $A$ containing $N$ or if $G/N$ has a subgroup with a certain property then there is a corresponding subgroup of $G$ with that same property?. Is this the way to understand 'bijection' in the context of a problem?

Comment: No, not every property can be transferred like that. Bijection just means a one-to-one and onto function as I explained. A property that is both preserved and reflected by the bijection is normality. Most properties of group will *not* be preserved.

Comment: Is there a way to show normality is preserved without using the correspondence theorem (i.e., Fourth Isomorphism Theorem)? Also, while I couldn't find it, I remember you had asked somewhere about a linear algebra book. I might offer a second opinion other than that of the author (Axler). His book - must only be the 3rd edition - is outstanding. Probably the best book I've seen for somewhat upper-level math. Plus it's used in the vaunted Harvard Math 55 course, so no slouch. Thanks. With regards,

Comment: Hi. I was wondering if when you say in the 'side remark' that the map is a lattice isomorphism one can define a binary operation on each of those sets so that a homomorphism makes sense, or if the term 'lattice isomorphism' should be interpreted more loosely? Thank you. I apologise for any misconception.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine making a giant chart of all the subgroups in the group $G$. I believe Dummit and Foote actually has a few illustrated for you. If not, the subgroups of, say, $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ will do nicely. Now, in your diagram, draw an arrow from subgroup $H$ to subgroup $K$ exactly when $H \subset K$. It might keep things tidier if you only draw an arrow to the "next largest" subgroup. The drawing you make helps you understand the subgroup structure of your group. You see all the subgroups and how each is contained in the other.

Now, find a normal subgroup. If you're working with $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, all of them are normal since the group is abelian. Since its normal, you can quotient and obtain a brand new group $G/N$. You can then go through and make this "subgroup chart" for this group. If you did things correctly, you can now see what the lattice isomorphism theorem is saying. The picture of the subgroup structure of $G/N$ should look exactly like all the subgroups of $G$ sitting "above" $N$. Each subgroup $K \supset N$ should correspond to a unique subgroup in $G/N$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have question though. Because of this bijective property can I conclude something like: If a subgroup of $G$ has a certain property then there is a subgroup $A/N$ of $G/N$ that has the same property with $A$ containing $N$ or if $G/N$ has a subgroup with a certain property then there is a corresponding subgroup of $G$ with that same property?. Is this the way to understand 'bijection' in the context of a problem?

Comment: You certainly can't do this for any property of the subgroup. For instance, if the $H$ property is "has order 16", then you can't say it's corresponding subgroups $H/N$ also has the property "has order 16"! All the bijection is saying is that each subgroup over $N$ has a unique subgroup in $G/N$ it corresponds to, exactly in the same way that every letter of the English alphabet can be given a unique integer between 1 and 26 it corresponds to. Have you encountered bijective functions before? That is the way in which they are using the term here.

Comment: I edited my question, so that my question might be more clear to you. Thanks for your time and answers. I really appreciate it.