# Intuitive explanation of the fourth isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I "get" the first three, but I just cannot understand what the fourth one is trying to say. For what it's worth, I am reading them from Dummit and Foote, and I am talking about the isomorphism theorems in group theory.

Comment: Which one are you calling the fourth? The lattice theorem, aka correspondence theorem?

Comment: Yeah, the book also calls it the lattice theorem

Comment: If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then picking a subgroup of $G/N$ is "the same" as picking a subgroup of $G$ that contains $N$. The first is the image of the second via the projection $G \to G/N$.

Comment: Did you look at the answers to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442507/explanation-how-to-use-the-lattice-isomorphism-theorem? Could you let us know what's missing? As it currently stands, your question is quite vague.

Comment: I did not see that when I originally searched, thank you M Turgeon I will read that now!